# Prove that $ \mathbb{B}(0,1] \not\subset \sigma \{ \big( \frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n} \big] : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

I want to prove that $ \sigma \{ \big( \frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n} \big] : n \in \mathbb{N}  \} = \mathbb{B}(0,1]  $

i.e, the sigma algebra generated by $\{ \big( \frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n} \big] : n \in \mathbb{N}  \}$ is equal to the Borel sigma algebra of $(0,1]$

$\mathbb{B} (0,1] $ is defined by $\mathbb{B} (0,1]  = \{ (0,1] \cap B : B \in \mathbb{B}( \mathbb{R} ) \} $, where $\mathbb{B}( \mathbb{R} )$ is the Borel sigma algebra of $ \mathbb{R} $

**Here's my attempt:**

$\subset$:

Let $ n\geq 1 $ be an integer, then $ 1/n \leq 1 $. We also have $0 < 1/(n+1)$. This implies that

\begin{equation}
\Big(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \Big] \subset (0,1]
\end{equation}

we know that sets of the form $(a,b] \in \mathbb{B}( \mathbb{R} ) $ for any $a \leq b$.    Then

\begin{equation}
\Big(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \Big] =  (0,1] \cap \Big(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \Big] \in \mathbb{B}(0,1]    
\end{equation}
This implies that

\begin{equation}
\Big\{ \Big( \frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n} \Big] : n \in \mathbb{N}  \Big\} \subset  \mathbb{B}(0,1]    
\end{equation}
since $ \mathbb{B}(0,1] $ is a sigma algebra, we get
\begin{equation}
\sigma\Big\{ \Big( \frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n} \Big] : n \in \mathbb{N}  \Big\} \subset  \mathbb{B}(0,1]    
\end{equation}

$\supset$:

I want to show that $ \mathbb{B}(0,1] \subset \sigma \{ \big( \frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n} \big] : n \in \mathbb{N}  \} $

Let $A \in \mathbb{B}(0,1] $ then $A = (0,1]\cap B $ where $B \in \mathbb{B}( \mathbb{R} ) $. This implies that $A \subset (0,1]$ and $A \subset B$. But at this point I'm stuck, I don't know how to proceed.

**My questions are:**

1. Do you know if these sets are equal? if so,
2. Do you have any hint that could help me to prove the equality?
3. Do you know some references where something similar to this problem is done?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don't think that is true. For example $[a,1)$ for $\frac12<a<1$ is unlikely to be in $\sigma((\frac{1}{n+1},\frac1n]:n\in\mathbb{N})$ Tipically you require the endpoints of your intervals to form a dense set.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Do you have any idea how find a value $a \in (1/2,1)$  such that $[a,1) \not\in \sigma ( (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}] : n \in \mathbb{N}  )  $ ?

Comment: No $(a,1]$ with $a>\frac12$ is is the the $\sigma$-algebra of generated by the harmonic intervals in $(0,1]$. Even the interval $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ is not in that $\sigma$ algebra, neither are the singletons  $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Comment: The statement of the problem is false.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I've been thinking about what said above, but I'm not able to prove it.  I think that there's something about the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma \{ (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}] : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ that I don't understand.  Could you explain me why the singleton $\{1/2\}$ is not in the  $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Let $I_{n} = (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$, you say that $A\in \sigma \{ I_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \} \iff A = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_{n} $. But what about intersections and complements?.

Comment: The complement of a union of "harmonic" intervals will be also the union of "harmonic" interval. The point is that your generators are a disjoint partition of $(0,1]$. In general, of $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a partition of $X$, then the $\sigma$-algebra generated but the elements of the partition consists of sets that are countable unions of elements of the partition.

Comment: @OliverDiaz yes, you are right!. And there's no way that $\{1/2\} =\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_{n} $, where $I_{n} = (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$. Thank you!